# index.html:29 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

//Trying to create a clock neo style, did the css and html everything good except the chrome says the error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
        const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
        const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");

        setInterval(() => {
            Let day = new Date();
            Let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            Let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            Let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
            hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: “Let” is trivially incorrect: it should be “let”. Using the correct case is important. The strings at the end are also trivially incorrect as they do not start and end with the same quote symbol.

Answer (score 1):

let is a keyword for declaring variables in JS and it should be lowercase.

If you just type `Let a = 1;` in your console you will see the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
        const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
        const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");

        setInterval(() => {
            let day = new Date();
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Also, help me with
hr.style.transform = 'rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`; 
error states: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector("#hr");
        const mn = document.querySelector("#mn");
        const sc = document.querySelector("#sc");

        setInterval(() => {
            let day = new Date();                       //small l
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + (hh + mm / 12) + "deg)";
            mn.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + mm + "deg)";
            sc.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + ss + "deg)";        //wrong argument
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```